# Fixed-effects contrasts in Matlab coefTest function

Tags: matlab, regression

what does the Fixed-effects contrasts mean in the Matlab `coefTest` function?

I am looking at the examples given by the Matlab official tutorial:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmixedmodel.coeftest.html#bt1pl74-1

In the Shift example, they have specified a fixed-effects contrast as `[0 1 -1]`. I don't understand what are those `0`, `1`, and `-1` means.

When calling `pVal = coefTest(lme,[0 1 -1])`, it can test if there is any difference between the evening and morning shifts. But I don't understand why. How about if I want to test if there is any difference between evening and night shifts? How can I modify the contrast matrix?

Comment: _Fixed-effects contrasts, specified as an m-by-p matrix, where p is the number of fixed-effects coefficients in `lme`. Each row of H represents one contrast. The columns of H (left to right) correspond to the rows of the p-by-1 fixed-effects vector beta (top to bottom), returned by the [fixedEffects method](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmixedmodel.fixedeffects.html)._ from the docs you linked. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which shows what you're trying to achieve

Comment: (at least from the PoV of someone who doesn't know any MatLab), you seem to be asking multiple questions, but you're generally only supposed to ask one question per question post. If that's the case, please amend this post by splitting it into multiple question posts.